# Is variable assignment synchronous in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Say we have

```
var x =3; 
var y = 4;
var z = x*y;
console.log(z);
```

How do we know it won't print an undefined variable z?

- If it is asynchronous, is there a function used to assign values to variables with a callback so we can be certain of their values when using them.
- If it is synchronous, then when loading modules like

```
var express = require('express');
```

Wouldn't that be pretty slow when you load a few of them in one script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are JavaScript functions asynchronous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141118/are-javascript-functions-asynchronous). This thread should clear up any questions you have.

Comment: So nodejs is just normal javascript? I thought the entire point was that it is executed asynchronously. That still doesn't answer my question of whether it is slow to load multiple requires in one script.

Comment: http://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2012/08/13/javascript-module-loaders-necessary-evil/

Comment: when you load modules with require most of the time it is not over the network (The files are on the server) so it wont be a long time. You might be thinking about requesting over the network which has latency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is variable assignment synchronous in nodejs?

Yes, it is.

Actually, any sequence of statements is executed synchronously.

You may be getting confused with the following type of situation:

```
var x = LongRunningAsyncTask();
console.log(x);
```

Here, `LongRunningAsyncTask` cannot return its result, since it is not yet known. Therefore, `x` probably won't be what you want, which is why, assuming `LongRunningAsyncTask` is implemented in callback style, you need to write

```
LongRunningAsyncTask(function callback(x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

or if `LongRunningAsyncTask` returns a promise, then

```
LongRunningAsyncTask() . then(x => console.log(x));
```

or using async functions:

```
async function foo() {
  var x = await LongRunningAsyncTask();
  console.log(x);
}
```